# How to create a view based on chosen type of data in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, user-interface

How to display different json files in the same view?

I have 3 json files:

```
 {"streetAddress": "Kosterijland 20", "postalCode": 3980, "city:" : "Bunnik", "country" : "Netherlands" }
 {"firstName": "Anna", "age": 39, "lastName:" : "Kowalski"}
 {"test": "value", "test2": "value2"}
```

I want to have generic method that will display the files like this:

```
streetAdress: Kosterijland 20 
postalCode: 3980
city: Bunnik
country: Netherlands

OR

firstName: Anna
age: 39
lastName: Kowalski

OR
test: value
tet2: value
```

How can I do that? **I want to make it generic, so when I add another json file with different properties I dont have to change the code**

`myService.ts` class for retrieving the data using http client:

```
  private url5 ="./assets/temp-data/location-entity-test.json";

  getEntityDetails(){
  return this.http.get(this.url5, {responseType: 'text'});
  }
```

`component.html` class for displaying the json:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of displayObjectKeys;  let i = index">
 {{ item }} - {{ displayObjectValues[i] }}
 </div>
```

`component.ts`class:

```
json: any;
displayObjectKeys = [];
displayObjectValues = [];

constructor(private linkedEntityVocabulariesService: 
LinkedEntityVocabulariesService) { }
ngOnInit() {
this.linkedEntityVocabulariesService.getEntityDetails()
        .subscribe(data=>this.json=data);

}
```

**PS. I know that html page is fine but I dont know how to get the properties and values in ts file and I dont know if the http request is good for this type of operations. Please help me**

Comment: yes... show your code

Comment: ngx-datatable is a great tool to dynamically create client tables.

Comment: I dont have any code, I just know that its possible to do that but I dont know how unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You could preprocess the objects you want to display into arrays if keys and values and render them seperately.

```js
dogObject = {"name": "woofy", "age": 42, "weight": "a ton"};
carObject = {"color": "red", "power":"1.31GW"};

displayObjectKeys = [];
displayObjectValues = [];

selectObjectToDisplay(selectedItemToDisplay) {
  let item = null;

  if(selectedItemToDisplay === car) {
    item = carObject;
  }
  if(selectedItemToDisplay === dog) {
    item = dogObject;
  }

  if(!item) {
    return;
  }

  this.displayObjectKeys = Object.keys(item);
  this.displayObjectValues = Object.values(item);
}
```

```html
<button (click)="selectObjectToDisplay("dog")"></button>
<button (click)="selectObjectToDisplay("car")"></button>
```

now you have the keys and values extracted.

then you could do something like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of displayObjectKeys;  let i = index">
  {{ item }} - {{ displayObjectValues[i] }}
</div>
```

this should render the car props as

color - red

power - 1.31GW

And when the user switches the object to display, just call the selectObjectToDisplay() method and pass the new object inside.

**BUT**

this is very dirty and the properties will be rendered as they are defined.

Comment: But this is not making it generic at all, every time I get another type of data I have to go back and change the code